# Background not displaying html

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to have a background picture display behind my header. However for some reason the image is not displaying. I am fairly new to html and css but have got the background image to display on other occasion. Am I missing something or do I have to change some lines? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

here is my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>My logo</h1>        
    </div>  

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<section class="home-main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is foo</h1>
    </div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 70em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix::after,
section::after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/* typography
================= */

.unstyled-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* header
================= */

header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 1em;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 900;   
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: .75em; 
}

@media(min-width:40rem) {

    .logo {
        float: left;
    }

    nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
    }

    nav {
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    nav a {
        font-size: 1.04em;
    }
}

/* home-main
================= */

.home-main {
    background-img: url('../manjitcss/img/manjit-main.png'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10em 0;
}
```

Comment: If you open your browser's console, are there any errors?

Comment: As @cwanjt writes, you need to check for 404 errors. Is the path to the image correct? Otherwise it surely won't show up.

Comment: no errors and I have displayed that image on a different project so I know the path works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ankit, your class `home-main` needs to change the `background-img` property to `background-image`. There is no alias for the background images called `background-img`. See [MDNs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) reference for `background-image` css property.

I created a codeply project with your code and modified the property using the correct name. You can view it [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/zGpGIzHip9).

Corrected property:

```
.home-main {
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10em 0;
}
```

Comment: just realized that and posted an answer but will upvote because indeed that was my mistake!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very big error of attention from my part, the problem was simply I wrote background-img instead of background-image!

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 70em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix::after,
section::after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/* typography
================= */

.unstyled-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* header
================= */

header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 1em;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
    font-weight: 900;   
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: .75em; 
}

@media(min-width:40rem) {

    .logo {
        float: left;
    }

    nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
    .logo {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin-top: -.5em;
    }

    nav {
        margin-top: 1em;
    }

    nav a {
        font-size: 1.04em;
    }
}

/* home-main
================= */

.home-main {
    background-image: url('https://res.cloudinary.com/rss81/image/upload/gw.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 10em 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>My logo</h1>        
    </div>  

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<section class="home-main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is foo</h1>
    </div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The "background-**img**" property is wrong. You should use "background-image":

```
.home-main {background-image: url('../manjitcss/img/manjit-main.png');}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp